# centos install nginx error : requires libunwind.so.8()(64 bit)

Tags: nginx, centos, yum, centos7

I install nginx on centos 7 And met problem
Please help me

Message:

```
Error:Package:gperftools-libs-2.4-5.el7.x86_64(epel)
          Requires: libunwind.so.8()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. @Nika Archvadze's answer fixed the problem for me, but it's been downvoted, I suppose because it's a bit sparse.

Anyway, probably a good idea to start with

```
yum update
```

then

```
yum install yum-utils
```

will install the yum-config-manager package.
then

```
yum-config-manager --enable cr
```

will enable the continuous release repository, which is probably already installed, but if not you can install it like this before enabling it

```
yum install centos-release-cr
```

Now you will have access to the libunwind package, which is in the continuous release repository, so you should just be able to

```
yum install nginx
```

without any problems

Comment: didnt fix the issue for me... same description as above. running centos 7.1. I'll update with a comment if/when i find an approach that works here

Answer (score 1):

```
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable cr
yum -y install nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

The package is available in the Centos 7 Continuous Release (CR) Repository. once enable the cr repo able to complete the installation with out any issue.

Following is the command to enable the cr repository.

```
#yum-config-manager --enable cr
```

Source: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/85814/juno-installation-error-returned-1-error-package-gperftools-libs-24-5el7x86_64-epel/